# Interface and Implementations with Separate Templates

Tags: java, interface, implementation, stringtemplate

I have a Java interface with several implementing classes.  Each implementation class needs its own associated (sub)template.  At runtime I add a collection (List) of objects implementing my interface to my ST.  How can I have each object in that list rendered by the appropriate template?

Example code:

```
public interface foo {...}
public class bar implements foo {...}
public class baz implements foo {...}
```

I would like to have a top-level ST for the interface foo, and each concrete/implementing class has its own ST as follows,

```
foo.st
bar.st
baz.st
```

I would like to pass a `List<foo>`, which contains a mix of `bar` and `baz` instances, to the foo ST and have the foo ST call the appropriate sub-template (`bar` or `baz`, depending on the subtype) for each element of the list.

I suppose I could create a `Map<String /* template name */, foo /* either bar or baz */>`, but it feels like by doing so I'm leaking the fact that I'm using StringTemplate into my data model design.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show some example code?  I'm unclear on what a "sub template" is in this context, and the same goes for "rendered."

Comment: Sure, assume the following Java definitions,

Comment: (sorry, submitted to soon and the edit timer expired)

Sure, assume the following Java definitions,

public interface foo {}

public class bar implements foo {}

public class baz implements foo {}

I have defined a main template, and templates for each implementing class as follows,

main.st
bar.st
baz.st

In my controller I add a List of foo (interface) objects to the main ST.

From the main ST, if the implementing type is bar, I want to call bar.st.  If the implementing type is baz, I want to call baz.st.

Does that help?

Comment: Could you put the code in the question please?  The lack of formatting makes it too difficult to read in the comments.

Comment: @markspace, thanks for replying.  I've added code snippets to help explain what I'd like to do.